# why std::cout not printing map

Tags: c++

i try making a snake game first step to create map but the map is not being loaded why?

the map should look like a square with #

yes this from tutorial

here my code:

```
class snakeGame
   {
   public:
       bool gameOver{true};
       const int i_WIDTH = 20, i_HEIGHT = 20;
       int head_x, head_y, fruit_x, fruit_y, score;

       enum eDirection{ STOP = 0, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, LEFT };
       eDirection dir;
```

initliaze

```
void snakeGame::setup()
{
gameOver = false;
dir = STOP;

head_x = i_WIDTH / 2;
head_y = i_HEIGHT / 2;

fruit_x = rand() % i_WIDTH;
fruit_y = rand() % i_HEIGHT;

score = 0;
```

}

```
void snakeGame::draw(int ii_WIDTH, int ii_HEIGHT)
{
    //system("clear");
    //draw map
    std::string firstlast(ii_WIDTH + 2, '#'); 
    std::string leftright = '#' + std::string(ii_WIDTH, ' ') + '#'; 
    std::cout << firstlast << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ii_HEIGHT; ++i)
        std::cout << leftright << "\n";
    std::cout << firstlast;
```

}

int main code
here:

```
int main()
{
    snakeGame snake;
    while(!snake.gameOver)
    {
        snake.setup();
        snake.draw(20, 20);
        snake.input();
        snake.logic();

    }
    cout << "work!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not all of your code. In particular, this does not show how `i_WIDTH` and `i_HEIGHT` are initialized, and it doens't show where or even whether `snakeGame::draw` is actually called.

Comment: snake game and standard output stream? This will always give poor results. Standard output (std::cout) is not same thing as terminal screen.

Comment: C++ is not Java. `this->` is unneded for accessing class members.

Comment: Clearly the problem is not with this code. You've made a common beginner mistake. The printing isn't working therefore the printing code must be at fault. But programs are made up of lots of interdependent parts and the whole thing stops working if one of the parts doesn't do it's job. So, in short, whatever the error is, it's not in the code you have shown us. Show more code and maybe someone will be able to tell you where the real problem is.

Comment: FYI -- You could simplify this whole thing by using `std::string` instead of nested `for` loops calling `cout` for every single character. [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68ca026cd845b637).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the code still not working..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i thought using `this->` make my code faster

Comment: @Ok. -- We need a [mcve], which you still haven't provided.  I provided a function that outputs exactly what you are attempting to output -- what in there will make the code "not work"?  Here is what I suggest -- change `draw` to do exactly what the code is that I linked to.  Make it take two parameters instead of your mystery `i_WIDTH` and `i_HEIGHT` values.  You not only will have a function that *should* work, you can test it by changing the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: @Ok `this` makes the code go faster. Strange belief. I've heard that ALL CAPS makes the code go faster because the compiler is a bit deaf. Seriously there is no programming language in the world where adding some incantation like `this->` magically makes the code go faster. If there is a simple way to make code go faster the compiler will do it **all the time** without you asking for it.

Comment: @Ok So based on the latest edit. The problem seems to be that `gameOver` is true, and so the draw routine is never called. It's true that `setup` sets it to false, but at the moment there is no proof that `setup` is ever called.

Comment: there code update take a look @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Ok. Your `setup` code should be a constructor, that way you can't forget to call it.

Comment: @Ok. -- Does `draw` ever get called?  Why not get rid of your loop, and simply call `draw` to verify that indeed, a square `#` output will be drawn?  Anything else, it is a logic bug, as already mentioned, in you not calling `draw`.  That's how you develop programs -- you verify independently, that each piece of it works correctly.  Once you verify that each piece works, **then** you put together the program that integrates each piece.

Comment: do you look down i already put the main int also, logic is not used yet i just draw a map

Comment: @Ok. Yes I looked at main, and my reasoning is correct. **If** you are not calling `setup` then that explains why nothing gets drawn, because the while loop is never entered. Paul's suggestion to narrow down this problem is also a good one, have you tried it yet?

Comment: @Ok.  Now prove that `draw` gets called.  Is it so hard to simply change `main` to this: `int main() { snakegame snake; snake.draw(20, 20); }`?  What do you see when you change `main` to that?

Comment: @john it still not working

Comment: @Ok. I know it's not working, if you have tried some new change, then please explain what it is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie snake.draw(20, 20);?

Comment: @Ok. -- You're really making this much tougher than it should be:  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9145c64478406c9).  So the issue is not the `draw` function -- it is that you are not calling it.  Now I'm wondering if your original draw code actually worked, but the reason is that you never called the function.

Comment: @john i use paulmckenzie method to draw map and call setup function

Comment: @Ok Show us the code. It's very hard to work from descriptions of code.

Comment: @Ok. In the latest version of `main` posted you are **NOT** calling `setup`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie call what???

Comment: @Ok. Call `setup` **BEFORE** the while loop. **BEFORE!!!**

Comment: @john what do you mean `latest version of main?`

Comment: @Ok. You keep editting the code , so I just mean the current version posted there.

Comment: @Ok -- Let me say this -- you are risking being downvoted if you cannot follow the advice given to you.

Comment: @Ok. The whole point here (which me and Paul have being saying for ages) is that the while loop is not being entered. Therefore any code you put **inside** the while loop can have no effect on your program. Call `setup` **before** the while loop.

Comment: @john that print the map! but it printing infinitely

Comment: @Ok. Right, one bug fixed, another dozen to go, it's progress at least. If you need more help, ask another question.

Comment: the only thing left to do is system("clear"); am i right?

Comment: @Ok. I doubt it. system("clear") clears the screen, it will not stop your program running infinitely.

Comment: thanks everyone it work finally working, topic solved

Comment: simply put the setup function before while loop like @john said

Comment: Can you explain why you thought that using `this->` makes the code "faster"? Why would it be "faster"?